# Встроить форму поиска Яндекса или гугла вместе с подсказками

Tags: javascript, поисковые-системы

Можно легко встроить себе на кастомную дефолтную страничку браузера форму поиска яндекса или гугла, которая будет вести на `http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=...` но у этого не будет живых подсказок.
Есть ли способы встроить с ним?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам сюда

[яндекс - поиск для сайтов](http://site.yandex.ru/)

вот пример как сделать по инету :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/y3pnoj3m/